# Show there are sequences of functions that converge uniformly to f on E if f is a bdd measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let f be a bounded measurable function on E.  Show that there are sequences of simple functions E, {$\phi_n$} and {$\psi_n$}, such that {$\phi_n$} is increasing  and {$\psi_n$} is decreasing and each of these sequences converge to f uniformly on E.

I know by simple approximation lemma, for all $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists simple functions $\phi_n$, $\psi_n$, defined on E such that $\phi_n$< f < $\psi_n$ and 0 < $\psi_n$ - $\phi_n$< $\epsilon$ on E. How do I show that these functions are uniformly convergent?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216199/sequences-of-simple-functions-converging-to-f?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approximation (from below) has
$$
\phi_n := \sum_{k=0}^{n2^n-1}k2^{-n}1_{E_{n,k}} + n1_{F_n},
$$
where
$$
E_{n,k} := f^{-1}([k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}))
$$
is defined for $n=0,1,\ldots$ and $k=0,1,\ldots,2^n-1$ and
$$
F_n:=f^{-1}([n,\infty))
$$
is defined for $n=0,1,\ldots.$

Note that if $f$ is bounded, then $F_n$ is empty for $n$ large enough. Since $f-\phi_n<2^{-n}$ on $F_n^c$ (which is the whole space for large enough $n$), we conclude that the convergence is uniform. This holds similarly for the approximation from above.